# Symfony YAML : Formatting the Output

Tags: php, html, arrays, symfony, yaml

I am using the Symfony YAML Component to model and output a yml file.

What I want to achieve is the following:

```
id: my-page
name: My Page
fields:
  pageTitle: My Page Title
placeholders:
  project-main:
    - component: MyComponent
      fields:
        imageSmall:
          src: /path/to/image.jpg
        imageMed:
          src: /path/to/image.jpg
```

I am almost managing that, just need help to understand how I need to form the line from componentName onwards. The result I'm getting at the moment is the following:

```
id: my-page
name: My Page
fields:
    pageTitle: 'My Page Title'
placeholders:
    project-main: { component: MyComponent, 0: { fields: { imageSmall: 'src: /path/to/image.jpg', imageMed: 'src: /path/to/image.jpg' } } }
```

Whilst this is the PHP Code I'm using to obtain this, is the following:

```
use Symfony\Component\Yaml\Yaml;
use Symfony\Component\Yaml\Exception\ParseException;

$array = array(
    "id" => "my-page",
    "name" => "My Page",
    "fields" => ["pageTitle" => "My Page Title"],
    "placeholders" => ["project-main" => array("component" => "MyComponent", array("fields"=>array("imageSmall" => "src: /path/to/image.jpg","imageMed" => "src: /path/to/image.jpg")))]);

$yaml = Yaml::dump($array);

file_put_contents('file.yaml', $yaml);
```

Anyone can help put me on the right track :) ?

**

- UPDATE

**

I have followed the tip in the comments and updated the PHP as follows:

```
$array = array(
    "id" => "my-page",
    "name" => "My Page",
    "fields" => ["pageTitle" => "My Page Title"],
    "placeholders" => ["project-main" => ["component" => "MyComponent", "fields"=>array("imageSmall" => "src: /path/to/image.jpg","imageMed" => "src: /path/to/image.jpg")]]);

$yaml = Yaml::dump($array,4);

file_put_contents('file.yaml', $yaml);
```

After this, my output is as follows:

```
id: my-page
name: My Page
fields:
  pageTitle: My Page Title
placeholders:
  project-main:
    component: MyComponent
    fields:
      imageSmall:
        src: /path/to/image.jpg
      imageMed:
        src: /path/to/image.jpg
```

So I have moved a bit, but still getting "component: MyComponent" instead of "- component: My Component". Any tips on solving this one last issue :) ?

Comment: The second argument of the `dump()` method is used to control at which level the dumper switches to the inline notation. Its default value is `2`. You probably want to increase that for your use case like this: `$yaml = Yaml::dump($array, 4);`

Comment: @xabbuh I tried that, but the output is exactly the same :/

Comment: I can see a different result. Which version of the Yaml component do you use?

Comment: Ok yes indeed - now it changed. The only thing is that in the notation, it still stays as "        component: MyComponent" instead of "        - component: MyComponent"

Answer (score 2):

To control the level at which the dumper switches to using the inline notation you have to pass the desired level as the second argument to the `dump()` method (the default value is `2`).

To get the expected structure while dumping you need to adjust the input array which currently does not represent what you expect it to be:

```
use Symfony\Component\Yaml\Yaml;

$array = [
    'id' => 'my-page',
    'name' => 'My Page',
    'fields' => ['pageTitle' => 'My Page Title'],
    'placeholders' => [
        'project-main' => [
            [
                'component' => 'MyComponent',
                'fields' => [
                    'imageSmall' => [
                        'src' => '/path/to/image.jpg',
                    ],
                    'imageMed' => [
                        'src' => '/path/to/image.jpg',
                    ],
                ],
            ],
        ],
    ],
];

$yaml = Yaml::dump($array, 6);
```

Comment: I still have exactly the same issue, where it's showing "component: MyComponent" instead of "- component: MyComponent" and the "fields" are on the same level instead of a child :/

Comment: Can you update your description with the exact code that you have right now? I am pretty sure that your `$array` variable is not composed as you expect it to be.